# Recycler view item enter animation not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I followed a tutorial for animating recyclerview item but the animation is not working iam confused that whether the animation is applied or not.

**Activity.Java:**
The updated code was here i tried with the button click but i dont know how to call the animation method from the onBindHolder form the adapter

```
private void setupRecyclerView() {
              RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        final LayoutAnimationController controller =
                AnimationUtils.loadLayoutAnimation(this, R.anim.layout_animation);

        recyclerView.setLayoutAnimation(controller);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(specialistListAdapter);
    }


  //placed a dummy button onclick to check animation working or not
 public void reloadData(View view) {
        runLayoutAnimation(recyclerView);
    }

private void runLayoutAnimation(final RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    final Context context = recyclerView.getContext();

    final LayoutAnimationController controller =
            AnimationUtils.loadLayoutAnimation(context, R.anim.layout_animation);

    recyclerView.setLayoutAnimation(controller);
    recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
    recyclerView.scheduleLayoutAnimation();
}
```

**layout_animation.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layoutAnimation
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:animation="@anim/item_list_animation"
    android:delay="15%"
    android:animationOrder="normal"
    />
```

**item_list_animation.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="-20%"
        android:toYDelta="0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
        />

    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="0"
        android:toAlpha="1"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
        />

    <scale
        android:fromXScale="105%"
        android:fromYScale="105%"
        android:toXScale="100%"
        android:toYScale="100%"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
        />
</set>
```

**Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 23):

I am late in answering this question but I was facing the same issue while following the same tutorial and after trying a bundle of different things I realized that I didn't added the attribute: `android:duration` in the `set tag` in **item_list_animation.xml** file which is same as your case. So the **item_list_animation.xml** XML becomes now:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime">

    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="-20%"
        android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator" />

    <alpha android:fromAlpha="0"
        android:toAlpha="1"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator" />

    <scale
        android:fromXScale="105%"
        android:fromYScale="105%"
        android:toXScale="100%"
        android:toYScale="100%"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
        />

</set>
```

**Note:** on changing the dataset you need to reapply the animation on the RecyclerView because calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` at any time will cancel the animation. You can reapply the animation by simply calling:

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
recyclerView.scheduleLayoutAnimation();
```

Answer (score 8):

If you're using `LiveData` & `ViewModel` (from Android Architecture Components) make sure you calling `recyclerView.setLayoutAnimation(controller);` in viewmodel.yourListLive().observe(){}.
Something like this:

```
  vm.getGamesPageList().observe(this, games -> {
    if (games == null)
      return;
    LayoutAnimationController animationController =
    AnimationUtils.loadLayoutAnimation(v.getContext(), ANIM_RES_ID);
    v.setLayoutAnimation(animationController);
    adapter.submitList(games);
    ...
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all you need to load the animation in the recycler view either in xml or programatically

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"                                        
android:layoutAnimation="@anim/layout_animation"/>
```

**OR**

```
LayoutAnimationController animation = 
AnimationUtils.loadLayoutAnimation(ctx, R.anim.layout_animation);
recyclerview.setLayoutAnimation(animation);
```

Also you need to call the method in OnBindViewHolder like `runLayoutAnimation(YOUR_RECYCLER_VIEW)`.

Comment: already animation was loaded programatically that you can see in the runLayoutAnimationfunction but how come i call the method in onBindViewHolder

Comment: In the onBindViewholder whenever  you have some action to perform you need to call that method.Ex say click of some item of you want to delete a row then in the onclickListener you have to call that.

Comment: Also you dont need that recycler view object in the adapter.You can get context like  yourViewHolder.itemView.getContext();

Comment: but in this tutorial (https://proandroiddev.com/enter-animation-using-recyclerview-and-layoutanimation-part-1-list-75a874a5d213)  the runlayoutanimation method is called inside the fragment only

Comment: i cant able to call the method from the adapter thats y calling the method in onCreate method

Comment: It is for animating the adapter when event happens.If you call in oncreate you wont notice the animation as it happens only once..Instead you should call it when a event happens..say on click of a button something.That time it wil show you the animation properly.

Comment: Also you can use specialistListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: Not able to find runLayoutAnimation() method.