# android recyclerview layoutanimation not working in stock android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, layout-animation

android:layoutAnimation not working in stock android phones

```
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/communityUnitsRV"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:adapter="@{adapter}"
            android:layoutAnimation="@anim/layout_animation_from_bottom"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view9"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
            tools:listitem="@layout/item_community" />
```

In other phones its working.Tested in MI A3,Nokia 7.1 and Mi note 5 pro(It's working in this one and other two are stock android.)

Comment: Checkout this : https://blog.usejournal.com/recyclerview-android-layoutanimation-not-working-7e4f3e6da9f

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recycler view item enter animation not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46681597/recycler-view-item-enter-animation-not-working)

Comment: I already tried the above solutions,but its not working.